# Add a Stock Item Attribute to the Sales Order Line Grid Acumatica

Tags: c#, attributes, acumatica

I have a stock items attribute added called ACCITEMS which is a multi select combo box and I have to pull those values to the respective sales order line when inventory id is selected, at the moment only 1 attribute value displays instead of multiple selected attributes.

````
        [PXDBString(250, IsUnicode = true)]
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Accessories Items")]
        public virtual string UsrAccessoriesFrmStkItems { get; set; }
        public abstract class usrAccessoriesFrmStkItems : PX.Data.BQL.BqlString.Field<usrAccessoriesFrmStkItems> { }
        #endregion ```

    ```protected virtual void SOLine_InventoryID_FieldUpdated(PXCache sender, PXFieldUpdatedEventArgs e, PXFieldUpdated InvokeBaseHandler)
        {
            InvokeBaseHandler?.Invoke(sender, e);
            SOLine row = (SOLine)e.Row;
            if (row == null) return;
            CSAttributeDetail CSAns = PXSelectJoin<CSAttributeDetail, InnerJoin<CSAnswers, On<CSAnswers.attributeID, Equal<CSAttributeDetail.attributeID>>,
                              InnerJoin<InventoryItem, On<InventoryItem.noteID, Equal<CSAnswers.refNoteID>>>>,
                              Where<InventoryItem.inventoryID, Equal<Required<InventoryItem.inventoryID>>,
                              And<CSAttributeDetail.attributeID, Equal<Required<CSAttributeDetail.attributeID>>
                              >>>.Select(Base, row.InventoryID, "ACCITEMS");
                  
                SOLineExt rowExt = row.GetExtension<SOLineExt>();
                rowExt.UsrAccessoriesFrmStkItems = CSAns.Description;        
        }```
````

Answer (score 0):

Add a user field which selects the attribute.  The user field will display your answers.
I haven't tested fully but it should be close.

```
#region UsrDiscountCategory
    [PXString(510)]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName="Discount Category")]
    [PXDBScalar(typeof(SearchFor<CSAnswers.value>.In<
        SelectFrom<CSAnswers>.
        InnerJoin<InventoryItem>.On<InventoryItem.noteID.IsEqual<CSAnswers.refNoteID>>.
        InnerJoin<SOLine>.On<SOLine.inventoryID.IsEqual<InventoryItem.inventoryID>>.
        Where<CSAnswers.attributeID.IsEqual<discCatAttr>>>))]
    public virtual string UsrDiscountCategory { get; set; }
    public abstract class usrDiscountCategory : PX.Data.BQL.BqlString.Field<usrDiscountCategory> { }
    #endregion

public class discCatAttr : PX.Data.BQL.BqlString.Constant<discCatAttr>
{
    public discCatAttr()
      : base("DISCCAT")
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use the UsrAccessoriesFrmStkItems field selecting event and fill the value.

aspx:

```
<px:PXDropDown runat="server" ID="edUsrAccessoriesFrmStkItems" DataField="UsrAccessoriesFrmStkItems" />
```

Event:

```
protected virtual void SOLine_UsrAccessoriesFrmStkItems_FieldSelecting(PXCache cache, PXFieldSelectingEventArgs e)
    {
        SOLine row = e.Row as SOLine;
        if (row != null)
        {
            List<string> allowedValues = new List<string>();               

            foreach (CSAttributeDetail detail in PXSelectJoin<CSAttributeDetail, InnerJoin<CSAnswers, On<CSAnswers.attributeID, Equal<CSAttributeDetail.attributeID>>,
                                                 InnerJoin<InventoryItem, On<InventoryItem.noteID, Equal<CSAnswers.refNoteID>>>>,
                                                 Where<InventoryItem.inventoryID, Equal<Required<InventoryItem.inventoryID>>,And<CSAttributeDetail.attributeID, Equal<Required<CSAttributeDetail.attributeID>>>>>.Select(Base, row.InventoryID, "ACCITEMS"))
            {
                allowedValues.Add(detail.Description);
            }
 e.ReturnState = PXStringState.CreateInstance(e.ReturnState, 225, true, typeof(KNMCMagentoSetup.customerClasses).Name, false, -1, string.Empty, allowedValues.ToArray(), allowedValues.ToArray(), false, null);
            ((PXStringState)e.ReturnState).MultiSelect = true;
        }
    }
```